# Why is the Button in this case validating the TextBoxes?

Tags: asp.net, aspbutton

It looks very simple, but becoming increasingly frustrating. I am working with a ASP.NET WebForm where I have the following code for `ButtonClear` that clears the text that is entered in the `TextBoxes`:

```
protected void ButtonClearAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Text = string.Empty;
    TextBox2.Text = string.Empty;
    TextBox3.Text = string.Empty;
    TextBox4.Text = string.Empty;
}
```

Code in `.aspx` file:

```
<asp:Button ID="ButtonClearAll" runat="server" Text="Clear" OnClick="ButtonClearAll_Click"/>
```

**Problem:** By clicking `ButtonClearAll` once, the four `TextBoxes` are clearing fine. But on subsequent click, the `RequiredFieldValidators` of the 4 `TextBoxes` are getting called and are validating the assigned `TextBoxes` to print the appropriate error statements next to each `TextBox`.

What to do?

Comment: Learn Javascript.   Forget the Validators.   Realise that life is tough once you step off Microsoft's beaten path, and that even though it's initially tougher, you're far better off knowing each tech in isolation, free of proprietorial stabilisers that seem to lower the barrier of entry, but actually just bring that barrier crashing down on your head the minute you want something different.

Comment: I know. And to be frank, I am experiencing that the hard way. #JavaScriptIsDope

Comment: We all do, sir.   I arrived on the .NET scene in 2001.  I was MS's target audience, the boy who didn't know web programming but fancied doing it anyway.   By 2004, I'd banned every server control at our firm except Repeaters and Literals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default any button, invoking any post-back, is going to invoke the validation first.  You can disable validation for a particular button with [the `CausesValidation` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.causesvalidation):

```
<asp:Button ID="ButtonClearAll" CausesValidation="false" ... />
```